# Thumbnail Navigation Problems with css position

Tags: css, navigation, position, positioning, thumbnails

I'm trying to create a thumbnail navigation for a slideshow. Below the main images will be a line of what appears to be dots, when you hover over them a preview appears.

I got this from a tutorial that was originally designed to be a next and prev navigation, but I am trying to convert it.

http://codepen.io/smalltrades/pen/sjrqm

I would like the dots to be spaced evenly across the bottom of the window, but as I am not completely fluent in css I haven't been able to find the right combination of settings. Currently all the dots are stacked on top of eachother.

Any thoughts?

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ekrvy
float left the a with fixed size